# Google Cloud Run: How to diagnose user firewalls blocking API calls on my React site?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, networking, web-applications, google-cloud-run

I have a React 17 / TypeScript web application deployed to Firebase on GCP in region nam5 (us-central). This front-end makes calls (axios) to a back-end Python application also on GCP, in Cloud Run in region us-central1.

- The front-end is hosted at my main domain:
  `https://myapp.mysite.com`.
- The back-end is hosted on the default domain: `https://mybackend-abcdefghij-uc.a.run.app`
- The site works normally for almost all users on various devices, networks and countries.

**The problem is that for a small number of users, API calls are failing (though the front-end loads normally).**

I strongly suspect this is firewall-related. I was able to get a live screen feed from one of our users where the console showed `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` for all the API calls. From the back-end logs, these calls never reach our API. We have only seen the issue with users in the US, and know one of these uses Spectrum as their ISP.

#### Fixes I have tried

1. I was able to resolve the issue with the one user willing to screen share by having them set their DNS settings manually, and using Google's servers (`8.8.8.8`/`8.8.4.4`). However, I can't expect all my users to do this.
2. I reached out to Spectrum to see if their default firewall blocks this type of traffic / our site but they were totally unwilling to provide any information.
3. My first suspicion was that the firewall dislikes that `mysite.com` is making calls to an external domain `run.app`, so I have set up DNS mapping so the back-end is now hosted at `https://api.mysite.com`, and deployed an updated front-end so that the calls now go to this address. However, I have no way to verify this has yet resolved the issue as none of our team were able to replicate the problem on any device.
4. Moving the entire back-end over to Google Cloud Functions, even at the default address `https://us-central1-myorg.cloudfunctions.net/myapp` resolves the issue entirely. This makes me think perhaps my assumption about external domains was wrong, unless some firewalls have the `cloudfunctions.net` domain whitelisted, but not the `run.app` domain. I would prefer to not have to switch my infrastructure entirely over to Cloud Functions.

How do I go about diagnosing this issue and replicating it?

Comment: Did you confirm that you don't have any ingress settings or firewall rules on the Cloud Run end that restricts certain IPs?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Yes, I did. All IPs are allowed (auth is done via a regular bearer token in the header)